# Run Length Encoding

Tags: c++, strings, interview-questions, compression

> Given an input string, write a function that returns the Run Length
>   Encoded string for the input string.
>
> For example, if the input string is “wwwwaaadexxxxxx”, then the
>   function should return “w4a3d1e1x6″.

The following is my implementation:

```
string length_encoding(const string& s)
{
    char c = ' ';
    int num = 0;
    string result;
    string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
    for(; it != s.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(*it!=c)
        {
            if(num!=0)
            {
                stringstream ss;
                ss << num;
                string num_s(ss.str());
                result += num_s;
            }

            c = *it;
            result.push_back(c);

            num = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            num++;
        }       
    }

    stringstream ss;
    ss << num;
    string num_s(ss.str()); 
    result += num_s;

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a bug. If your input string begins with a space then you don't prefix the number with a space.

```
Input:           "    AAAA"
Output:          "4A4"
Expected Output: " 4A4"
```

This is easily fixed by outputting the character and count at the same time.

Problems: Magic values

```
char c = ' ';
```

Magic values cause all sorts of problems you should really use a value that can never be a character. In this case convert to an int and make it -1

```
int c = -1; // This is guaranteed to be a value that will never be a character.
```

Use the ability to declare variables inside the `for(;;)` statement unless you really need the iterator after the loop.

```
string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
for(; it != s.end(); ++it)

// easier to write and read as:

for(string::const_iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it) 
{
    // Also because `it` is scopped is does not pollute the
    // code with a variable that is not used after the loop.
}
```

This piece of code:

```
            stringstream ss;
            ss << num;
            string num_s(ss.str());
            result += num_s;
```

Is repeated in two places. Refactor it into its own function.
You will also find that such a function already exists in boost `std::lexical_cast`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a C++ guru, but for what they are worth, I have some comments:

- it would be better to evaluate s.end() just once (outside the loop). Correction:  this won't help.
- the function fails if `s` starts with a space
- you have duplicate code turning an int into a string. Perhaps use C++11 `to_string` or write your own a function, such as:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  static std::string to_string(T num)
  {
      std::stringstream ss;
      ss << num;
      return ss.str();
  }
  ```

Comment: Calling s.end() only once will not help anything. Most implementations already cache the value so that there is no cost to multiple calls. This is also a bad idea as it makes the code hard to read (as it is not what you expect).

Comment: Ah, ok.  I'm learning C++ (so arguably I shouldn't be commenting on others' code) and have seen this suggestion around so I took it to be true. Thanks for the correction :-)